# DataContractJsonSerializer throws SerializationException, complains about unexpected type even though I've specified it with KnownTypeAttribute

Tags: c#, .net, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

Say I have the following classes:

```
[DataContract]
class Entry<T>
{
    [DataMember]
    public T Data { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
class DataList<T>
{
    [DataMember]
    public IList<T> Collection { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(User))]
class ExtendedDataList : DataList<object>
{
    [DataMember]
    public string SomeExtraParameter { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
class User
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I've applied `KnownTypeAttribute` to `ExtendedDataList` since that class extends the base class of general type `object`, and it will store different kinds of objects in the list. In this example, I've marked a known type of `User` since I know it'll contain `User` objects.

Here's the serialization code:

```
var user = new User { Name = "Bob" };
var users = new ExtendedDataList { Collection = new List<object> { user } };
serialize(users);
```

with

```
static void serialize<T>(T obj)
{
    var entry = new Entry<T>();
    entry.Data = obj;

    var stream = new MemoryStream();
    var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Entry<T>));
    serializer.WriteObject(stream, entry);

    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    var r = new StreamReader(stream);
    var s = r.ReadToEnd();
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s);
}
```

the line `serializer.WriteObject(stream, entry);` throws a `SerializationException` saying that the type `User` was not expected and that I should use `KnownTypeAttribute` to specify it. But I did (indirectly)!

How can I make this work? I cannot move `KnownType` to the `Entry<T>` class, because it needs to be general. Why can't `DataContractJsonSerializer` see that `ExtendedDataList` specifies the `User` as a  known type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way to get it to work, but *it still doesn't explain why `DataContractJsonSerializer` is ignoring the `KnownType` attribute I've applied to `ExtendedDataList`*.

It seems that `DataContractJsonSerializer` isn't smart enough to notice the `KnownType` attributes that I've specified on the `ExtendedDataList` class; apparently it only honors the known types that I've attached to the `Entry<T>` class since `typeof(Entry<T>)` is the type that I give to the constructor of `DataContractJsonSerializer`

I want `Entry<T>` to remain general, and I do not want to litter it with all sorts of `KnownType` attributes. So instead, I use the following class definition:

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType("KnownTypes")]
class Entry<T>
{
    [DataMember]
    public T Data { get; set; }

    public static IEnumerable<Type> KnownTypes()
    {
        var attrs = typeof(T).GetTypeInfo().GetCustomAttributes<KnownTypeAttribute>();
        return attrs.Select(attr => attr.Type);
    }
}
```

This uses reflection to get the `KnownType` attributes attached to the inner type `T` and then passes these types to whatever data contract serializer that serializes `Entry<T>`.

Note: requires `using System.Linq` and `using System.Reflection`.